# How can I set the Profile Image in a DataTemplate on AppShell to a Url Source

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, base64

I am trying to set an Image to that of a base64 image result from my API

[FlyoutHeaderTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoA5z.png)

The Code for the Image Is Located within AppShell.xaml as follows

```
<Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="40" BackgroundColor="#272C33">
                <Frame CornerRadius="100" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                    <Image x:Name="ProfileImage" Source="ImageAssets.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Image>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
```

I used ImageAssets.png as a local resource which is being shown but I need to set it to the base64 image result from the api. This is for a profile picture.

But I do not know where to access the Image Property within Xamarin forms.
I've tried accessing it within the C# code on AppShell.xaml

Comment: you can't access template items by name.  You need to use data binding.  And you should decode your base64 image and write it to the file system

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason said, you could use the data binding. For more details of data binding, you could check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/

The code below is used to convert base64 string byte[] and then convert the byte[] to Image Stream which is assigned to Image Control. You could set the Image Stream for property of data binding.

```
       //get the base64 image from api
        string base64Image = "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";

        byte[] Base64Stream = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);
        xfImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Base64Stream));
```